# How to access HTTP headers of request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-headers

I know I can access an HTTP request's GET parameters in AngularJS with

```
$location.search().parameterOfInterest
```

But how do I access HTTP headers of the request?

I'm not using $http here. I'm asking about request to an AngularJS web page.

This question and answers makes me believe this is could be not possible:
[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231)

Comment: Could you please tell us more information? What do you want to do? There are others ways to send data. So, why do you need use that headers?

Comment: Well, the context is not relevant here. My question is that if I can access headers in JavaScript and/or AngularJS or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [request interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) that is called with an HTTP configuration object. An [HTTP configuration object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) has a header property that you can freely access / modify inside your interceptor.

The [response object of promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns) also has a header property that you can access.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using $http here. I'm speaking about request to a AngularJS web page.